# Clicking on button to open custom villager gui

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm working on a trading system that uses item to item trading. My first thought is to use a custom villager and then, somehow, have a command open the trading system whenever a player pushes the correct button. I would love to use a system like this but I don't know if it is possible or not. My only other option is to have a command block test for button push, then activated another command block to `/testfor` the amount in currency and if that is true to then `/clear` the required amount, then `/give` the player the bought item and then reset the redstone with another command. This would work but the world I'm building is a sky survival and the command blocks would have to be in the render distance, so I'm trying to keep the size down. Any help with the first idea would be appreciated and size constraining in the next would be also. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

You can write the commands in a "function". Than you don't must build a command-block-system in the spawn chunks.